# Element type "application" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: android, styles, themes, manifest

I'm having some trouble with my code.

By the way, I am learning from thenewboston and currently on tutorial 11, I got this error while doing tutorial 10 and I don't plan to continue to the next tutorial until this is fixed.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thenewboston.sammy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
```

It says:
Element type "application" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

```
        <activity android:name="com.thenewboston.sammy.StartingPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and tell us result:

Remove from layout file this

```
<resources>
    <string name="total_is_zero"> Total is zero</string>
</resources>
<resources> 
    <string name="add_one"> Add one</string>
</resources>
<resources>
    <string name="subtract_one"> Subtract one</string>
</resources>
```

and move it into one file res/values/strings.xml like

```
   <?xml version= "1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>
   <resources>
        <string name="total_is_zero"> Total is zero</string>
        <string name="add_one"> Add one</string>
        <string name="subtract_one"> Subtract one</string>
    </resources>
```

And res/layout/activity_starting_point.xml file should looks like

```
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height= "fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/total_is_zero"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
        />

       <Button 
           android:layout_width="250dp" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/add_one"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:id="@+id/bAdd"
           />
        <Button 
           android:layout_width="250dp" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/subtract_one"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:id="@+id/bSubtract"
           />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Okay thank, this helped me so much. But now, an error appeared in the Manifest. -___-

Comment: Do you have style named AppTheme in your res/values/style.xml?

Comment: No I don't have it. Should I put it?

Comment: You are trying to attach style that does not exists. Remove that line, for now, and try it.

Comment: I am talking about android:theme="@style/AppTheme" , of course.

Comment: The more I remove or try to fix things the more it is giving me errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have spaces afaik in string resources. I would change `@string/Your total is 0` to `@string/total_is_zero` and then create that string resource in `strings.xml`:

`res/values/strings.xml` create this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="total_is_zero">Your total is 0</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks for the help, I really appreciate it! It's still giving me errors, I'm not sure if it's that I placed it in the wrong place or not but can you show me?

Comment: Everywhere you use `@string` you're doing a similar thing which will need to be changed.

Comment: It's giving me errors like "This file should be placed in a values/ folder, not a layout/ folder", also like, "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix
 - Unexpected text found in layout file: "Your total is zero", also, "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/Your_total_is_0').". I've updated my code in the original post as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using @string then Eclipse expects to find a resource called "Your total is 0" in the 
strings.xml file.  e.g you could create a string there called total and define its

```
<string name="total">Your total is 0</string>
```

You would then reference this in your xml as

```
<android:text= "@string/total">
```

If you just want to display the text you could replace your textview field by

```
<android:text= "Your total is 0">
```

Hope this is clear

Comment: It's giving me errors like "This file should be placed in a values/ folder, not a layout/ folder", also like, "Multiple annotations found at this line: - Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix - Unexpected text found in layout file: "Your total is zero", also, "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/Your_total_is_0').". I've updated my code in the original post as well.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly sugest you to read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and to try to understand how resources works in Android.

If you want to add string resources, you need to create string.xml file and to put it into res/values/ directory.
In that file follow this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
    <string name="total_is_zero">Your total is 0</string>
</resources>
```

Then you can assign desired string resource to your element in xml via

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width= "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/total_is_zero"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    />
```

Comment: I understand what you guys mean by the resources, and I did that. But now, it is giving me errors and is underlining my first <resources> in red, and same in my "name="total_is_zero">". It told me to put it in the values instead of layout and I did as it said.

Comment: Now it's just giving me this error on my second <resources> "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element
 - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed."

Comment: Can you, please, update your q and put complete res file that produce error you mentioned?

Comment: I just did, take a look at it.